# Is it possible to use .pkl file in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, machine-learning, speech-recognition, pickle

Is it possible to deploy .pkl file in flutter?
My .pkl file contains a simple function that returns the spectrogram of the input audio file.
this step represents preprocessing the audio file before inserting the spectrogram to .tflite model.

Comment: looking forward to the anwser

Comment: I did a quick research. To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to do so. I solved the problem by creating a flask server and process my data there. My app is no longer offline but it's working.

Comment: yeah I'm keeping that as a plan B so i guess i have no other choice for now